# Lua c++ lib sethook: Gives error with hook function arg

Tags: c++, lua, lua-c++-connection

Been googling for a while, have no idea whats happening.
So I have a class called luaScript which handles, lua scripts ( Surprising! I know. ), which in it's current state, could not exit or pause scripts currently being executed.

I found out about hooks, which allow me to run code every time something happens.
Also found a cool stackoverflow question from 2009 showing how to use them.

Copied code, got hook done, tried to compile, and... nothing.
Nothing but an error saying that the function I passed ( `void hookRoutine(lua_State *L, lua_Debug *ar)` ) was incompatible with the type `lua_Hook` ( Which I find total bs because `lua_Hook` is defined as `typedef void (*lua_Hook) (lua_State *L, lua_Debug *ar);`
 which as far as I know is exactly what I gave it. )

This is the code I copied:
`lua_sethook(mL, hookRoutine, LUA_MASKCOUNT, 0);`
`mL` being the lua instance and `hookRoutine` being the hook.

Things I have tried so far:

```
lua_Hook hookRoutine
lua_sethook(mL, &hookRoutine, LUA_MASKCOUNT, 0);
lua_sethook(mL, lua_Hook(hookRoutine), LUA_MASKCOUNT, 0);
```

I am completely stumped on this and have been googling for hours, can someone please explain what kind of stupid error I made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `hookRoutine` is a regular member function of your class.  It has to be a static member function instead because Lua does not know anything about C++ and the `this` pointer.  You need to find some other way to pass the `this` pointer to your hook function in case you need it (probably by storing it in the Lua state, in the registry).